# find through command prompt

Tags: windows, find, dos

How to find all the *.txt files in any directory(i.e. c:\,d:\ etc.)  through command prompt?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will search from root directory and its all accessible sub folders regardless of the folder you currently in.

```
dir \*.txt /s
```

or

```
dir c:\*.txt /s
dir d:\*.txt /s
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

```
c:
cd \
dir /s *.txt
d:
cd \
dir /s *.txt
```

Comment: Although it will only search subdirectories, so you'd need to `cd` to the root directory. I also don't know of a way to get it search all drives (i.e. if you're in C:\, it won't search D:\ automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dir *.txt`

Comment: "In any directory," he said. :-)

Comment: Oops, somehow I thought he wanted a command which he would run in that particular directory... :|

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR %%A IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO @call :dumpdrive %%A
echo Done...
goto :EOF
:dumpdrive
FOR /R "%1:\" %%B IN (*.txt) DO @echo.%%~fB
goto :EOF
```